# different themes in portrait and landscape for a ListView

Tags: android

I have a ListView which should have the "Theme" theme in portrait and the "Theme.Light" theme in landscape mode. How do I do that? The theme seems to be tied to the activity, and for the ListView I can only change the style, but I dont find a style which works.

Or, is there a way to change the activity's theme based on orientation? By code or prefereable by xml?

To be more precise and explain the reason: I try to start experimenting with the fragment compatibility library. The starting activity shows in portrait mode a list which looks best with black background. When I touch a list item, a second Activity starts and shows a ListView which better looks on white, so this second Activity has the Theme.Light. Works so far.

When I switch to landscape, I try to show both ListViews aside. The second one on the right *has* to have a white background. The first one on the left could stay on white also (so the whole activity could change the theme), but I'd like to see one on black and one on white, if possible. (I put both ListViews in Fragments, this is done and works. Only the colors are wrong.)

Any ideas?

Greetings, Joerg

Answer (score 0):

You would create a layout.xml file for each orientation, and put each in the proper folder according to the Android standards.

Then, you can set the different style as an attribute in each XML file.

Android will use the appropriate layout file automatically, depending on orientation.

Comment: I do that already. But exactly which are the style attributes? I tried for the ListView: style="@android:style/Widget.ListView.White", but this did not work.